# How to display data from server in angularv8

Tags: node.js, oracle11g, ionic4, angular8

I would like to display the name of the person who logged in the app. I tried this

```
getprotected() { 
return this.http.get(${this.url}/api/protected_things)
   .pipe( 
      catchError(e => { 
         let status = e.status; 
         if (status === 401) { 
            this.showAlert('You are not authorized for this!'); 
            this.logout(); 
         } 
         throw new Error(e);
      }) 
   ) 
}
```

**tab1.ts**

```
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  data = '';

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private storage: Storage, private toastController: ToastController, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.authService.getprotected().subscribe(res => {
       this.data = res['name'];
       });
  }
```

**tab1.html**

```
<p class="ion-text-center">Bienvenu</p>

  <p class="ion-text-center"><b>{{ data }}</b></p>

  <ion-button expand="full" (click)="logout()">Deconnecte Toi</ion-button>
```

but ts not working.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to access the data you need with `res.name`.

As a general rule of thumb, try logging your result.
A simple `console.log(res)` from within the `.subscribe()` will help you visualize the object you receive.

If the problem happens early, the chrome network inspector will help you detect the data you receive. Keep in mind that an empty object will not trigger your catch error. To know more about network tab in chrome: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1gAyQuIFQo&

By the way you should watch some tutorial, on youutbe you can find great material

Comment: thank you but nothing is showing stiill. im new in  coding can you please give me an example?

Comment: actually downvoting my answer it's not very kind of you. You have to paste the code of `authService.getprotected()` so i can see that too

Comment: sorry did i? my apologies

Comment: getprotected() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/protected_things`).pipe(
      catchError(e => {
        let status = e.status;
        if (status === 401) {
          this.showAlert('You are not authorized for this!');
          this.logout();
        }
        throw new Error(e);
      })
    )
  }